# Custom Sort Range

Tags: range

Just need to know how can I get the following code not to get me a type mismatch error. The last line which is commented out works but when i replace the Range("B2:B2000") with f it gives me a type mismatch error. Reason why I am not just using the last line instead since it works is because what if column B becomes Column C if i insert a new column in Column B. Is there something else that I need to add to the f to make it work?

f = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("PCR No.", Range("A1:AZ1"), 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("3. PMO Internal View").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Cells(1, f)

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("3. PMO Internal View").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("3. PMO Internal View").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
f, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
'Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```